# Reading from a text file and updating

Tags: c#, io

I am new to programming and I came across a problem and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

I use the line

```
    textBox2.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

To read from a text file and paste the contents in textBox2.

Now the issue is that the text file I'm try to read is a large (couple megabytes) text file. This text file contains logs from a program, new logs are always added at the bottom of the file. 
Now I want to update textBox2 if the text file is updated. However I am not sure how to do this in an efficient way. One way is to just read the whole text file again, but since the text file is so big, this is a very slow process.

I am interested in finding out a different and faster way to handle this. I'm not really interested in the exact code, I just hoped to find out in what direction I should look and what options I can consider.

Comment: you do not want to read the contents into a TextFile, you should read the contents into a List<T> or if necessary read into a RitchText field also state what the delimiter is as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, two obvious things you could check:

- The size of the file ([`FileInfo.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx))
- The last write time ([`FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetimeutc.aspx))

If you keep track of those, you should be able to detect when the file has changed - at least with a reasonable degree of confidence.

Additionally, you can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch for changes.

Also, you might want to consider keeping track of where you've read to - so you could just read the new data, by seeking to the right place in the file.

Finally, a `TextBox` may not really be the best user interface for a huge log file. If this is a *structured* log file, it would be good to have that structure represented in the UI - for example, one row in a table per log entry, potentially with filtering options etc.

Comment: thought: if I get notified every time the file changes I may get many notifications if it's a log file and every log line is flushed to disk..right? So, still, he should check only every X seconds, right?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You said: "Also, you might want to consider keeping track of where you've read to - so you could just read the new data, by seeking to the right place in the file." 

Do you have any tips to do this?

Comment: @Brick: If you know the length of the file at the time you last read it, you can just open a `FileStream` for reading, set the `Position` property, then create a `StreamReader` to read the rest of the data. Note that you'd need to be really careful around data races though, in terms of the file size changing between you reading the size and reading the data.

Comment: @Brick: and of course, only if you can be sure that the text you've already read does not change. That is, you only get text appended to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check every X seconds. If the file changed then update, if not, do nothing. You can keep the modification time of the file to know if it changed or not.